# Spark Scheduler Force Application To Run

Tags: apache-spark, scheduler

When there are multiple applications submitted to spark on the same cluster, spark orders them in first in first out fashion and no job can start until the previous has finished. I'm trying to find a way to make an application skip the queue and be the next application to run in the scheduler. Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything from documentation or the user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be that you cannot force an individual application or job to start ahead of another one if it was initiated after the first application / job.

However, you should make sure that you set up queues properly in your cluster so that your queues are not fighting for executors. In this case, one of the queues had the ability to use up to 100% of the total executors of spark. In that queue, a spark job was queued up and not processing because of some bug in their application / job. Because that queue in which it was run had access to up to 100% of the executors, each job after that, no matter what queue they were in, had to wait for it to complete before running and it backlogged the entire cluster.